# cannot install scipy on openshift

Tags: python, scipy, openshift

I want to install scikit-learn but this library needs scipy and numpy too.

I tried to add them on the setup.py but I had an error with numpy. I handle to install scikit-learn and numpy from virtenv, but I cannot install scipy.

I tried pip install scipy. The procedure finished without any problem but there isn't any scipy folder on site-packages.

Also, I tried to add only scipy on setup.py. The same as above. The procedure finished without an error but scipy isn't there.

Any help?

Comment: Did you check for errors in the output of the `push`?

Comment: cannot install numpy and scipy. I am trying right now at workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know openshift but maybe you can adapt the work that was done to install Atlas / numpy / scipy / scikit-learn on heroku:

https://github.com/dbrgn/heroku-buildpack-python-sklearn

In particular building scipy from source (using pip) requires a fortran compiler (e.g. gfortran) which is probably not installed on OpenShift by default.

**Edit**: a possible alternative would be to build binary packages for numpy, scipy and scikit-learn using the [wheel format](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and then point the pip install command to an OpenShift blob store that hosts the pre-built packages.

To make sure that the wheel package will work on OpenShift you will have to build them on the same OS (I think it's Redhat 6).

**Edit #2**: the `manylinux1` platform tag was designed to solve this issue and makes it possible to embed the third party libraries you need inside the wheel package. There should be official numpy and scipy wheel files for x86_64 linux. In the mean time you can build them your-self by following the instructions at: https://github.com/pypa/manylinux

Comment: Note an in addition to the wheels, you'll also have to upload the system libraries that your scipy is dynamically linked against, like libatlas.so, which are not likely installed on OpenShift.

Comment: Indeed. Alternatively it should be possible to build numpy, scipy and scikit-learn wheels with statically linked atlas as an alternative. However I don't know anyone who did that so far.

Comment: For scipy you will also need the fortran runtime library in addition to libatlas.so.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find more info `ssh`ing into your app ad typing `tail_all`.